# Calling methods from models.py inside views.py without creating instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

New to Django coming from .NET with an architectural question.

Inside my `models.py`, I have a concept called `city`. These cities can be enabled/disabled.

Inside my views, I want to retrieve all active cities under my view called `Cities`. I need to retrieve all active cities in many places, so I thought I'd make a method inside my `models.py` city class called `get_in_country`, so it looks like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_in_country(self, country_id):
        #return best code ever seen
```

Anyway, my question now is: how do I use this inside `views.py`?

Being an awesome noob, I of course tried this:

```
def country(request, alias):
    cities_in_country = City.get_in_country(1) #whatever id

    data = {
            'cities_in_country': cities_in_country, 
        }

    return render(request, 'country.html', data)
```

Now, you don't have to be Einstein (ahem, Jon Skeet?) to realize this will go wrong, as I haven't made an instance of City and will cause an exception:

```
unbound method get_in_country() must be called with City instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

So: how would you modify my code to use my new awesome submethod?

Comment: Since you want to filter all rows in the City table by Country, a custom Manager method like `City.objects.filter_by_country(country)` would be best pratice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `get_in_country` as a [static function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

By adding a decorator

```
@staticmethod
```

just before the class defenition as

```
@staticmethod 
    def get_in_country(self, country_id):
```

---

```
class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @staticmethod # Changed here
    def get_in_country(self, country_id):
```

Comment: Ah, static methods. The methods I always avoid in .NET ;-) When doing a static method, I assume you remove "self" ? If not, what do you provide as self?

Comment: You need to provide any `self` as argument. If you need to acess some class variables, pass the instance instead

Comment: But lets say my new static method is 'def get_in_country(self, country_id):', and I call it by saying City.get_in_country(current_country.id) - I will get an "get_in_country() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" error. How to fix that?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard No, you should be loosing `self` altogether. That is the def must look like `def get_in_country(country_id):`. For example http://ideone.com/wLA3g8

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot - it makes sense! :) Really a big help!